# Core Data Batch Updates

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I want to update core data entities but to pass different values in a batch process for example:

```
NSBatchUpdateRequest *batchRequest = [NSBatchUpdateRequest batchUpdateRequestWithEntityName:"Location"];
batchRequest.propertiesToUpdate = @{"distance": value};
```

i want to update distance with different value every example i found on the web update with a single value (Bool).Is that possible?

Thanks Spiros

Comment: I dont' think so there is way to do that.U can use parent and child context and make your update faster

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want a different value of `distance` for different Core Data instances, but all in one batch update-- no, that's not possible. `NSBatchUpdateRequest` request is designed to make the same update to a bunch of instances in a single step. Each one gets the same new values for the same properties. If you want to assign different values, you can't use batch updates.